# How do I detect changes that occur to one element of an Angular 2 reactive/dynamic form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to detect the change in one specific form element that was built using reactive forms.

I used `*ngFor` and `*ngSwitch` directives to build a reactive form as demonstrated in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html#. My form currently contains input type `text` and `file`. I use the change event to capture the file upload task so I need to detect changes in the `file` input element but not the `text` input element. This is where I run into the problem. The form built using `*ngSwitch` or `*ngIf` doesn't seem to trigger the `change` event. I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1dMfn7gmR3rHq6xcgr2a?p=preview) that can be used to recreate the issue I am facing.

The form works fine if I detect changes in each form element. (form2 in the plunker example)

Please see plunker in the link below for a recreation of the issue I am facing.
https://plnkr.co/edit/1dMfn7gmR3rHq6xcgr2a?p=preview

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, if you use rxjs;

```
this.form1.controls['image1'].valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Put this code in `ngOnInit` method after you create `form1` form group. Whenever value of `image1` changes, subscriber log the `data`.

**Edit**

Since the value of input which type is `file` never changed, you can not watch the changes as I said, sorry for that.

In plunker, all of your control type of form elements are `textbox`. This is the reason why you can not fire the event when you write `(change)` in only one element. Because your switch case is based on control type and all of form element's control type is `textbox`. Change the control type of inputs which types are `file` from `textbox` to `file`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still does not detect the change. https://plnkr.co/edit/1dMfn7gmR3rHq6xcgr2a?p=preview

Comment: lol wow. Thanks, I completely missed that. Thank you so much!